# Test value(s) for an invalid Linux path-name for Java code

Tags: java, unit-testing, path

I'm unit testing some Java code that must parse an input `String` as a path-name. I'm using Java 7, so the parsed value is a `Path` object.

The [`Paths.get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) method will throw an [`InvalidPathException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/InvalidPathException.html)

> if the path string cannot be converted to a `Path`

So, to check my parsing code is robust I need a test value that will cause `Paths.get` to throw that exception. That is, a `String` value that is not a valid path. What constitutes a valid path is system (even file-system) dependent, so I am specifically interested in a `String` that is not a valid POSIX path, or (failing that) not a valid Linux path.

Comment: I am answering my own question, as is [encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 0):

POSIX path-names [may not contain null characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311037/are-there-any-invalid-linux-filenames). Therefore a `String` that consists of a single NUL character (Unicode code-point 0) will be invalid. That is, the `String` `"\0"`. I can confirm that Open JDK throws a `InvalidPathException`, with the message `Nul character not allowed`, for this case.